# How do I close out of Google Navigation programmatically?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I am starting Google Navigation through an Intent:

```
private static final int  GOOGLE_NAV = 5;

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("google.navigation:q= some + address"));
startActivityForResult(intent,GOOGLE_NAV);
```

I then check if the user has reached his destination via a LocationListener. If the user has arrived, I want to close the Google Navigation activity.

```
if(hasArrived())
{
    finishActivity(GOOGLE_NAV);
}
```

However, my code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: im also stuck on this.. did you find how to do it?

Comment: I ended up do it manually on the device.

Comment: how was it solved? i need to close google navigation when users arrives his destination too

Comment: I've already answered that one. You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45279815/1734088)

Comment: Store your destination location and run service in background once you reach at your destination then open your activity instead of closing of Google Map.