# Is it possible to programmatically access the Google Maps' navigation history?

Tags: android, google-maps

I wonder if it possible to retrieve the Google Maps navigation history. In other words, is there a way of retrieving the recent routes taken/searched by the user of the Google Maps app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API available to **get** information out of the Navigation App. But you can **feed** some data to Maps to request a route through an Intent / URI.

But I don't think that the Maps app will save the whole route anyway, only the destination. The user selects any saved destination and you can get there from any source.

Comment: the destination list is accessible via API?

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva AFAIK no.

Answer (score 3):

**You can not finish Google Navigation App.**

There is only one work around which I found, 
Re-start the navigation with the current location, hence the navigation will automatically be finished.

```
public static void startNavigationIntent(Context activity, String destination)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + destination));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And then bring your app to the foreground.

```
Intent bringToForegroundIntent = new Intent(BackgroundLocationService.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                        bringToForegroundIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(bringToForegroundIntent);
```